# Ubuntu repository download iso 

Tags: ubuntu, repository

where can I download Ubuntu repository in `.iso` file directly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu team doesn't make a downloadable ISO of the repository contents to my knowledge. You should be able to easily create one yourself using [**APTonCD**](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) though, or download unofficial ones somebody has made from [**here**](ftp://ftp.leg.uct.ac.za/pub/linux/ubuntu-unofficial-packages-dvd/). APTonCD allows you to select which repositories or sections you want and download them as CD/DVD images so you can conserve bandwidth.

If you want, you can also try [**the long way**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352460) or [**purchase DVDs**](http://www.osdisc.com/cgi-bin/view.cgi/products/linux/ubuntu/repo.html) with the repository contents on them.

Answer (score 3):

See  ["How to make your own Ubuntu Repository DVDs"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352460).