# How can I download ubuntu packages in windows to install them on an offline ubuntu machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, download, packages, repository

How can I download ubuntu packages from online repos thhrough windows to install them later on an offline ubuntu machine?

this is related to this question:
[Ubuntu repository download iso](https://superuser.com/questions/135389/ubuntu-repository-download-iso)

if there are any ready-made iso's for 11.10 that include device drivers, language packs & software packages would be great for ubuntu users without an internet connection.

any ideas?

Comment: You'll find some good options on the **AskUbuntu** Question [How can I install software offline?](http://askubuntu.com/q/974/1352). It has high votes for [keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) and a tutorial reference too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800

Answer (score 16):

For similar needs, I run a small virtual machine in my windows machine. To download packages without installing you can use `apt-get download <package_name>`. The command will download the package to the directory that you run the command. You can then copy the packages to the host, then a flash drive, lastly to the machine that you use.

I know this may not be the most elegant solution but at least works for me.

**Oh, I forgot:** If you need dependency checking, you can run `apt-get -s install <package_name>`, copy the dependency line and just paste to `apt-get download` command.

**Update 2:** I looked to the manpage of the `apt-get`. It has a switch called `--download-only`. You can pass this to install & `apt-get` will get all the packages for you but won't install them. You can find your packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. An occasional `apt-get clean` will delete the files from the directory, so you can get the packages you want easily.

**Update 3:** To install the packages obtained with method in **Update 2**, you need to put these packages again in `/var/cache/apt/archives` in the offline machine. If you want to install packages you got with `apt-get download`, you can use `dpkg -i <package_file>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can search for and download them right on http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: It's not really feasible since it doesn't download any dependencies and in Linux every dependency has a ton of dependencies of its own. That's why they have that notice strongly encouraging you not to download packages that way, but to use a package manager instead.

Comment: Of course it is feasible. You just have to know what packages you need. Automatic dependency management was not a requirement of the original question.  The site above even tells you what the dependencies are for every single package. Also, not *every* dependency has "a ton" of other dependencies. If you know what you are installing and what it needs in order to work, you will be a lot better off when things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

While i haven't tested it yet [keyrx](http://keryxproject.org/) should allow you to create a manifest of things that need updating, download them on another system, and install them. I'm not sure if it handles packages that arn't already on the system however.

Comment: I assume you mean [keryx](http://keryxproject.org/). Your youtube link takes me to a clip called "Expert Cooking" :-)

Comment: This is what i get for SUing when ill ;p. Fixed, and thanks